# Grafana 2.4 default user timeout

Tags: grafana, graphite-carbon

I am trying to configure a session timeout for user inactivity on Grafana dashboard. I would like to know what the default timeout is for user inactivity. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the current docs:

> session_life_time
>
> How long sessions lasts in seconds. Defaults to 86400 (24 hours).

http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#session-life-time

I cannot find a release tag for Grafana 2.4 but the docs for 2.5 (which was released in 2015) look the same:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/v2.5.0/docs/sources/installation/configuration.md#session_life_time

UPDATE: This option was removed in Grafana 6.0. Grafana moved from user sessions to using short-lived tokens instead. The change is explained in the [release blog post for 6.0](https://grafana.com/docs/guides/whats-new-in-v6-0/#easier-to-deploy-and-improved-security) and in the [migration guide to Grafana 6.0](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/upgrading/#upgrading-to-v6-0).

The new settings are documented on the [user authentication docs page](https://grafana.com/docs/auth/overview/#login-and-short-lived-tokens)

These two settings replace the old `session_life_time` setting:

```
# The lifetime (days) an authenticated user can be inactive before being required to login at next visit. Default is 7 days.
login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_days = 7

# The maximum lifetime (days) an authenticated user can be logged in since login time before being required to login. Default is 30 days.
login_maximum_lifetime_days = 30
```

Comment: This option is removed in version 6. How do I do it now?

Comment: @Motoko this should help you: https://grafana.com/docs/auth/overview/#login-and-short-lived-tokens and this explains the change from user sessions to using short-lived tokens: https://grafana.com/docs/guides/whats-new-in-v6-0/#easier-to-deploy-and-improved-security